# Change value of primary key (ID of a particular record) when foreign key constraints exist

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Here's the basic gist of what I'm trying to do:

```
create table main(id char(1) primary key);

create table other (
  id int primary key auto_increment,
  main_id char(1),
  key m (main_id),
  constraint fk foreign key (main_id) references main(id)
);

insert into main(id) values('a');
insert into other(main_id) values('a');

update main inner join other on other.main_id=main.id
set main.id='b', other.main_id='b'
where main.id='a';
```

This results in a foreign key constraint failure. Is there any way to accomplish this without dropping the foreign keys (not really an option on my large production database)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this simply by temporarily setting `foreign_key_checks=0` in your session:

```
set foreign_key_checks=0;

update main inner join other on other.main_id=main.id
set main.id='b', other.main_id='b'
where main.id='a';
```

Another option is to configure the foreign key with the `ON UPDATE CASCADE` option so that if the primary key is updated on the parent table it will cascade to the child table:

```
create table main(id char(1) primary key);

create table other (
  id int primary key auto_increment,
  main_id char(1),
  key m (main_id),
  constraint fk foreign key (main_id) references main(id) on update cascade
);
```